# What should the dynamic query for the following SQL string be?

Tags: 7, database

What should the dynamic query for the following SQL string be?

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(s.name) AS site_list
FROM sites s
INNER JOIN publications p ON(s.id = p.site_id)
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$query = db_select('sites', 's')
  ->fields('p', array('id', 'name'))
  ->groupBy('p.id');

$query->addExpression('GROUP_CONCAT(s.name)', 'site_list');
$query->join('publications', 'p', 's.id = p.site_id');
```

Comment: Note that GROUP_CONCAT is a MySQL specific feature, make sure that there's no better way to solve this.

Comment: Note MySQL has a size limit on text returned by GROUP_CONCAT. The default value is 1024,so if you are querying to get a large number of items, it can truncate the results on you. It doesn't warn you, of course, and I couldn't even find anything in the error logs about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that query string directly with [`db_query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7.x), with the difference that database table names need to be wrapped in curly brackets.

```php
$query = db_query("SELECT p.id, p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(s.name) AS site_list FROM {sites} s INNER JOIN {publications p} ON p.id = s.site_id GROUP BY p.id");
$records = $query->fetchAll();
foreach ($records as $record) {
  // Do something.
}
```

I take that `ON s.id = p.site_id` really meant `ON p.id = s.site_id`, as `p.id` is the selected table field.

As [Berdir said](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39672/drupal-dynamic-query-with-group-concat/39675#comment40294_39675), `GROUP_CONCAT()` isn't implemented by all the database engines supported by Drupal; the query should be rewritten to avoid using it.

As [Introduction to dynamic queries](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/introduction-to-dynamic-queries) says, dynamic queries should be used:

- When the query parts vary depending on the context
- When other modules should be able to alter the executed query
- When porting Drupal 6 code that uses [`db_rewrite_sql()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.inc/function/db_rewrite_sql/6.x)

The following code (taken from [`comment_get_display_ordinal()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/comment_get_display_ordinal/7.x)) is an example of the first point.

```php
$query = db_select('comment', 'c1');
$query->innerJoin('comment', 'c2', 'c2.nid = c1.nid');
$query->addExpression('COUNT(*)', 'count');
$query->condition('c2.cid', $cid);
if (!user_access('administer comments')) {
  $query->condition('c1.status', COMMENT_PUBLISHED);
}
$mode = variable_get('comment_default_mode_' . $node_type, COMMENT_MODE_THREADED);
if ($mode == COMMENT_MODE_FLAT) {
  $query->condition('c1.cid', $cid, '<');
}
else {
  $query->where('SUBSTRING(c1.thread, 1, (LENGTH(c1.thread) -1)) < SUBSTRING(c2.thread, 1, (LENGTH(c2.thread) -1))');
}
return $query->execute()->fetchField();
```

As part of the query is added basing on some conditions, `db_select()` is used. The alternative would be using `db_query()` and concatenate the strings that form the query (which isn't preferable to using `db_select()`).

An example of the second point is code that needs to show a list of nodes to which the currently logged-in user has access. In this case, `db_select()` is used, and *node_access* is added to the query with [`SelectQuery::addTag()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddTag/7.x), which allows modules that implement [`hook_query_TAG_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/7.x) to alter the query, as explained in [Query alteration (tagging)](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/query-alteration-tagging).

The following code is an example of the third point. (See [`blog_feed_user()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21blog%21blog.pages.inc/function/blog_feed_user/7.x).)

```php
  $nids = db_select('node', 'n')->fields('n', array('nid', 'created'))
    ->condition('type', 'blog')
    ->condition('uid', $account->uid)
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->orderBy('created', 'DESC')
    ->range(0, variable_get('feed_default_items', 10))
    ->addTag('node_access')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchCol();
  $channel['title'] = t("!name's blog", array(
    '!name' => format_username($account),
  ));
  $channel['link'] = url('blog/' . $account->uid, array(
    'absolute' => TRUE,
  ));
  node_feed($nids, $channel);
```

That code is the Drupal 7 port of the following code.

```php
  $result = db_query_range(db_rewrite_sql("SELECT n.nid, n.created FROM {node} n  WHERE n.type = 'blog' AND n.uid = %d AND n.status = 1 ORDER BY n.created DESC"), $account->uid, 0, variable_get('feed_default_items', 10));
  $channel['title'] = t("!name's blog", array(
    '!name' => $account->name,
  ));
  $channel['link'] = url('blog/' . $account->uid, array(
    'absolute' => TRUE,
  ));
  $items = array();
  while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    $items[] = $row->nid;
  }
  node_feed($items, $channel);
```

If your query falls in one of those cases, and you are showing just part of the query, then you can use `db_select()`, for example as the following code.

```php
$query = db_select('publications', 'p')->fields('p', array('id', 'name'));
$alias = $query->innerJoin('sites', 's', '%alias.site_id = p.id');
$query->addExpression("GROUP_CONCAT($alias.name)", 'site_list');
$query->groupBy('p.id');
```